# Change Button Value/Display Text Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using a plugin (so I do not have access to edit HTML) for an age verification pop-up on my website. I want to change the text displayed on each of the two buttons, which is currently being pulled from the HTML value attribute.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOKYw.png)

This is the HTML for each button:

`<input type="button" name="confirm_age" id="confirm_age" value="I am 18 or older [Enter Site]" style="background-color:#2dc937; width:300px;" tabindex="1">`

`<input type="button" name="not_confirm_age" id="not_confirm_age" value="I am under 18" style="background-color:#cc3232; width:300px;" tabindex="1">`

Comment: Does `document.querySelector("#confirm_age").value = "New Value"`  work?

Comment: Yes you can try querySelector

Answer (score 0):

As @vanblart said you can use:

```
document.querySelector("#confirm_age").value = "New Value"
```

If the plugin takes its time to render the buttons you can wrap the above code in a timer with [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector("#confirm_age").value = "New Value"
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I have little to no Javascript experience. Do I need to wrap anything around the code you suggested? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you should wrap any JavaScript code in `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: Like so? 

`<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector("#confirm_age").value="Soy mayor de 18 años"
}, 2000);
</script>`

It isn't working (either option)...